# sandcastle BE0040 Error: wrong path

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sandcastle

I'm using the Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB) GUI to build documentation for a C# project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. In the Project Properties, the output path is set to "bin\x86\Debug\", but when I build the Sandcastle help file in the SHFB GUI, there is a

> Error BE0040: Project assembly does not exist

and references the path "\bin\Debug", not the output path specified in the project properties.

Where does SHFB get the output path from? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this problem. Following link is recommended for [SHFB online help and documentation](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/bd1ddb51-1c4f-434f-bb1a-ce2135d3a909.htm).

The ***BE0040 Project assembly does not exist*** error occurs if the assembly from a project file documentation source cannot be found.

The most likely cause of this error is that the project has not been built. Build the project so that the assembly exists and then build the help file project. In addition, check the Configuration and Platform settings on the documentation source to ensure that they are selecting the assembly that was built (i.e. Debug or Release). If they are not specified, check the settings in the GUI (if used) or the command line options (if built with MSBuild) for the correct settings. If not specified, they default to Debug and AnyCPU respectively.

Switching the platform target e.g. x86 may cause this too (different path, see below).

[image]

Please check the file names and folders when using SHFP GUI too.

[image]